# Why doesn't C# null-conditional operator use overloaded equality operator?

Tags: c#

C# 6.0 has intruduced new cool Null-conditional operators

```cs
    obj?.method();
```

which checks if obj is null, if it is, it stops further executing of statement. So the code is the same as if doing manually

```cs
    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        obj.method();
```

but (at least for me) more intuitive would be

```cs
    if (obj != null)
        obj.method();
```

the difference is, operator == can be overloaded, in the second case it is used, in case of the null-conditional operator overloaded oeprator is not used, it is always a null reference equality.

Is there particular reason why they have designed it this way? For me it seems counterintuitive and not consistent. I don't get `by design` explaination if the more natural is using == operator. Even the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) seems not to say it is reference equality.

`operation to its operand only if that operand evaluates to non-null.`

Comment: The operator should handle the case that something is `null`, not if something has a hidden functionality that makes it look like `null` but actually it's something else. Why something should return `true` for `Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)` and `false` for `obj == null`?

Comment: I can't think of a good reason why you'd ever implement your `==` operator in such a way that it would make a difference which of the two variants it chose.

Comment: It is implemented that way in Unity game engine, while it is not best example of good design - effectively it is very easy to use `?.` instead of `if (obj != null)` which results in exceptions in code. That's why I have asked.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah that is alas an oddity of Unity. The advantage of the standard implementation is that it can use `brtrue.s` which is likely faster than working out which `==` operator to run, and running it. It does mean if there is something that 'breaks the rules' so to speak (i.e. by saying that something that isn't `null` is equal to `null`), then - well it won't work so well...

Comment: @Andy: i guess it's this: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate. If you strongly disagree, let me know. Even if I reopen it though, I suspect it will be closed as `primarily opinion based` since unless the person who decided `Is there particular reason why they have designed it this way?` happens to read this question, we'll largely be hypothesising. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2020 may also be worth a read (since it is reasonably clear that the language designers don't support Unity's approach).